# Can conservative systems have unstable equilibrium points?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

In general, can conservative systems have a equilibrium(fixed) point which is unstable?
If so, I don't know why so in spite of these systems have conserved quantity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what quantity is conserved. Is the conserved quantity is a positive definite function of the state variables, then the answer is no. In general, yes, they can. Consider, for example, the system
$$
\dot x= y\qquad \dot y= x-x^3.
$$
It has a conserved quantity $E(x,y)=\frac12 y^2-\frac12 x^2+\frac14x^4$ and the origin is unstable:

[image: phase plane]